# simply accessing char array in a function by char pointer

Tags: c, string, pointers, printf

in this program i am accessing a global **char array** through a function pointer,changing string values with **address by address in char pointer** makes difference in global char array , but when changing the string as whole string it does't make any difference in the global array

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void function(char *string);

char str[20] = "Hello"; // global char array

int main()
{
    function(str);
    return 0;
}

void function(char *string)
{   
    int i;

    printf("%s\n",string);
    printf("%s\n", str);

    for(i = 0;i < strlen(string);i++)
        string[i] = 'a';    

    printf("%s\n",string);
    printf("%s\n", str);

    string = "jhony";

    printf("%s\n",string);
    printf("%s\n",str);        // here is the doubt 
}
```

**output**

```
Hello
Hello
aaaaa
aaaaa
jhony
aaaaa //how this supposed to print aaaaa even after we changed string into jhony
```

Comment: Your question is the classic example one might use to illustrate pointers.  Indeed, this is the expected behavior and your expectation is wrong.  In order to overwrite the data you must use something like `strcpy`.

Comment: To avoid such problems, use e.g. `std::string` to handle strings.

Comment: @Alf, the `c++` was likely included in error here.  All signs point to this being exclusively `C`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string = "jhony";
```

does not copy `"jhony"` to the memory pointed by `string`. Instead, it assigns address of  `"jhony"` to `string`.

So after that, `string` points at `"jhony"` while `str` stays unchanged.

---

As @BrianCain commented, to copy `"jhonny"` to the memory addressed by `string` you may use

```
strcpy(string, "jhonny");
```

Comment: why is that happening?

Comment: More generally, raw arrays in C++ only support assignment in the context of being members of structs, where assignment of the struct performs a nested array assignment. It's not very logical. It just is that way.

Comment: @siva This is just how C/C++ define it. Of course, if you use `std::string` instead of raw `char*`, the behavior will be different.

Answer (score 1):

This is because string is a local variable. When you set `string = jhony` you aren't changing str. You are simply changing what string is pointing too. After this there are two string constants defined, "aaaaa" and "jhony", the aaaaa string is not overwritten. Str is also still "aaaaa" since it was not overwritten by the assignment of johnny to string.

Answer (score 1):

string and str are both different pointers pointing to the same thing. Using the array
notation is the same as dereferencing so you were actually manipulating the underlying data and because they were pointing to the same thing the change was noted in both places.

When you set the pointer equal to the literal, there wasn't any dereferencing or array notation. This changed what the pointer pointed to but the underlying data was not touched. And so the change was not noted by the other pointer.

Setting a pointer equal to something changes its value in the sense that the value of a pointer is an address. That address is a reference to whatever the pointer points to but now the pointer points to a new address. In your case, the string literal.

Answer (score 0):

```
string = "jhony";
```

this statement has changed the string's value which means the variable string not points to global array any more, it now points to the new const string "johny" which stored in the function's stack